# how to read csv file using jquery and print data into an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, autosuggest

I have a csv file like this:

**tags.csv**

```
1140,ABCD
1142,ACBD
1144,ADCB
1148,DABC
```

Want to read this csv file using jQuery and print into an array to getting this data into input autosuggest:

```
   $( function() {
        var availableTags = ["ABCD","ACBD","ADCB","DABC",]; //want to print csv data into this array.
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
        });
    } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```js
/* this function reads data from a file */

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "tags.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) { 
            const parsedCSV = parseCSV(data) 
            $( function() {
                var availableTags = parsedCSV;
                $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                 source: availableTags
               });
             } );
      }
     })
})

function parseCSV(csv) {
    /* split the data into array of lines of type */
    const csvLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    /* loop throw all the lines a remove first part (from the start, to comma) */
    return csvLines.map(line => line.split(',')[1])
}
```

Comment: how to receive the id on input value only ? @Pain

Comment: You mean the `1140, 1142, 1144, 1148` ? replace `line => line.split(',')[1]` with `line => line.split(',')[0]`

Comment: i mean on autocomplete it will show `ABCD, ABDC` but its hidden value will be their mentioned value, do u got it?